# CoreData fetching issue: fetching entities with an array of specific days

Tags: swift, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

I have saved entities and gave them an attribute called "date". My goal is to fetch objects for a specific set of days. As Date (NSDate) objects are specific moments in time, i'm forced to create "day ranges" for every day i want to fetch.

How can i approach this effectively? Should i create N predicates for N days or create one big predicate with "AND" clauses? Are there clever ways to approach this common goal?

Comment: `NSCoumpoundPredicate` should be the one to use, creating an OR predicate for each days you want with "date >= StartOfDay AND date >= endOfDay`, for each day and compound them with a OR.

Comment: Ended up using compound predicates indeed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you need your data (so all events) multipe times, you should not fetch them on every request, better filter them.

For example:

```
var allEvents = [Events]()

...
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "events")
allEvents = try context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as! [Event]
```

And then, when you need them

**1. for a specific date**

```
let calender = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
eventsForSelectedDay = events.filter( { return calender.isDate($0.yourDateProperty, inSameDayAsDate: self.currentSelectedDate) == true } )
```

**2. for a date range**

```
eventsForSelectedDays = events.filter( { return $0.yourDateProperty >= dateFrom && $0.yourDateProperty < dateTo } )
```

Comment: So you would fetch all entities first, and then grab needed selection by filtering for specific ranges? Sounds good, but the reason i was searching for specific predicates was for memory reasons. Is there like a threshold for the amount of objects that should be fetched into memory (focussing on performance)? Other than that, nice answer.

Comment: isDate(_:inSameDayAsDate:): Returns true if the two NSDate instances are on the same day—delving into date components is unnecessary. Your example would be: `let filtered = events.filter { calendar.isDate($0.date, inSameDayAs: otherDate) }`